# Filtering a file with values over 0.70 using AWK

Tags: linux, awk, filter

I have a file of targets predicted by Diana and I would like to extract those with values over 0.70

```
>AAGACAACGUUUAAACCA|ENST00000367816|0.999999999975474
UTR3    693-701 0.00499294596715397
UTR3    1045-1053   0.405016433077734
>AAGACAACGUUUAAACCA|ENST00000392971|0.996695852735028
CDS     87-95   0.0112208345874892
```

I don't know why this script doesn't want to work if it seems to be correct

```
for file in SC*
do
  grep ">" $file | awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"}{if($3 >= 0.70)}{print $2, $3}' > 70/$file.tab
  
done
```

The issue is it doesn't filter, can you help me to find out the error?

Comment: The words "filter" and "extract" are ambiguous. Please [edit] your question to just say "print" or "delete", whichever it is you mean, and add the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

For a start, that's not a valid `awk` script since you have a misplaced `}` character:

```sh
BEGIN{FS="|"}{if($3 >= 0.70)}{print $2, $3}
#                           |
#                           +-------------+
#                              move here  |
#                                         V
BEGIN{FS="|"}{if($3 >= 0.70){print $2, $3}}
```

You also don't need `grep` because `awk` can do that itself, and you can also set the field separator without a `BEGIN` block. For example, here's a command that will output field 3 values greater than `0.997`, on lines starting with `>` (using `|` as a field separator):

```sh
pax> awk -F\| '/^>/ && $3 > 0.997 { print $3 }' prog.in
0.999999999975474
```

I chose `0.997` to ensure one of the lines in your input file was filtered out for being too low (as proof that it works). For your desired behaviour, the command would be:

```sh
pax> awk -F\| '/^>/ && $3 > 0.7 { print $2, $3 }' prog.in
ENST00000367816 0.999999999975474
ENST00000392971 0.996695852735028
```

> Keep in mind I've used `> 0.7` as per your *"values over 0.70"* in the heading and text of your question. If you really mean *"values 0.70 and above"* as per the code in your question, simply change `>` into `>=`.

Comment: It's supposed to work too, but I'm sorry to say it doesn't

Comment: @DiegoMunoz: then I would suggest there's something wrong with your `awk` :-) Those lines are actual output from my system so they do work. A few questions for you to answer: 1/ What is your OS? 2/ What is the output of `awk --version`? 3/ What is the actual output you are getting (exactly)? 4/ Which shell are you using?

Comment: I run the first script, removing `}` and putting it at the end as you suggested and it works. Thanks

Comment: If that doesn't work then you're probably in a locale where the decimal separator is comma (`,`) instead of period (`.`). Set `LC_ALL=C` before running the script to test that.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are running a for loop to kick off `awk` program multiple times(it means each time a file processes an `awk` program process will be kicked off), you need not to do that, `awk` program could read all the files with same name/format by itself, so apart from fixing your typo in `awk` program pass all files into your `awk` program too like:

```
awk -F\| 'FNR==1{close(out); out="70/"FILENAME".tab"} /^>/ && $3 > 0.7 { print $2,$3 > out }' SC*
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it's perhaps safe to regex filter in string mode, instead of numerically :

- `$3 !~/0[.][0-6]/`

if it started to interpret the input as a number, and does a numeric compare, that would be subject to rounding errors limited to float-point math. with a string-based filter, you could avoid values above

`~ 0 . 699 999 999 999 999 95559107901… (approx. IEEE754 double-precision of 7E-1 )`

being rounded up.

Comment: What if `$3` was `1.0` or, less likely but still worth considering, `5e-1`? Don't use regexps to do numeric comparisons, it's lengthy and fragile and just not necessary (unless the number exceeds the max or min value for a number in your system then a string comparison may be an option in some cases). In general, keep it simple and just do numeric comparisons for numeric input.

Comment: the 5e-1 case i didnt' consider, but shouldn't it properly handle 1.0 ?  the criteria explitcitly requires one zero left of decimal point, unless it's so poorly formatted it came in as "10.0e+0" or "0.1e+1"  in lieu of a "1".

Comment: You're right, it would find `1.0` - that's the other problem with a regexp approach, it's hard to understand!